PreserveHostHeader with WebTestClient fails
When setting PreserveHostHeader filter in spring.cloud.gateway.default-filters, WebTestClient ends up with a 500 error instead of 503 wanted.
// @AutoConfigureWebTestClient(timeout = "PT100S")
// ...
// private @Autowired WebTestClient testClient;
// ...

testClient.get().uri("/path/to/unavailable").exchange().expectStatus().isEqualTo(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);

A workaround involves manually setting the host header with .header("Host", "localhost").  but it seems to be a bad practice.
Any ideas how to fix this ?
